# VALIDAÇÃO DE INPUT

Tags: javascript, html, funções

Estou tentando verificar um input mas o alerta não aparece quando dígito o código.

Ao digitar o código no input deveria verificar se é igual à "S1A2G3E", se fosse era pra exibir "Código correto!" se não "Código incorreto". Mas não está funcionando.

Alguém consegue me ajudar?

```
<div class="question">
  <h1>Digite seu código de sorteio:</h1>
  <h3>Código para exemplo de teste: S1A2G3E</h3>
  <input type="text" id="fname" onfocusout="myFunction()">
</div>

function myFunction() {
    var codigo = document.getElementById('fname');

    if (codigo === 'S1A2G3E'){
        alert("Código correto!");
    } else{
        alert("Código incorreto.")
    }
}
```

Comment: não deveria pegar o atributo `.value` do seu input?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

O problemas está acontecendo no seguinte trecho:

```js
var codigo = document.getElementById('fname');
```

Observe que você está buscando o elemento cujo atributo `id` é **fname**, porém não está utilizando o valor dele (propriedade `value`). Com isso a comparação não está ocorrendo com o texto e sim com o **objeto** que representa o `input` na DOM.

Simplesmente, acesse a propriedade que irá funcionar:

```js
var codigo = document.getElementById('fname').value;
```

```js
function myFunction() {
  var codigo = document.getElementById('fname').value;

  if (codigo === 'S1A2G3E') {
    alert("Código correto!");
  } else {
    alert("Código incorreto.")
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="question">
  <h1>Digite seu código de sorteio:</h1>
  <h3>Código para exemplo de teste: S1A2G3E</h3>
  <input type="text" id="fname" onfocusout="myFunction()">
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado Marcos, problema resolvido. Estou treinando JS ainda, ajudou muito!!!

Comment: Top! Estamos aqui para isso.